# (18,9,8) self-dual quaternary codes vs S18

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, coding-theory

i am wondering about the form of S18. It is written that [18,9,8] self-dual quaternary codes is equivalent to S18.
there is a generator matrix of this quaternary code, ok, but how it can be equivalent to S18?

S18 is the symmetric group. S_{18} maybe better.

Comment: I may not be up to speed with coding theory, but I may still not be the only member who might be able to answer, but does not know what the heck is S18? I don't think it is a standard name of any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code $S_{18}$ was defined in 1978 in the article [F. J. MacWilliams; A. M. Odlyzko, N. J. A. Sloane, H. N. Ward: Self-dual codes over $GF(4)$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165%2878%2990021-3) as an extended cyclic code, see page 310.

In 1997, in [W. C. Huffman: Characterization of quaternary extremal codes of length $18$ and $20$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/18.623160) it was shown that up to equivalence, $S_{18}$ is unique among the extremal Hermitian self-dual $\mathbb F_4$-linear $[18,9,8]$ codes. The proof involves computer results. This should answer your question, I guess.

As a side note:
In the article [C. Bachoc; P. Gaborit: On extremal additive $\mathbb{F}_4$ codes of length 10 to 18](http://dx.doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.278), it is shown that every extremal even self-dual $\mathbb F_4$-additive code with some additional property (in the article, $s(C) = 0$) is equivalent to $S_{18}$.
This article was written in 2000. I don't know if there was any progress in the meantime.

Comment: I thought  S_18 must be special group, because it is always said this code is equivalent to S_18, nothing else. And I read all the paper you mentioned. And then I found the generator vector of S_18 in the paper "Classiﬁcation of Generalized Hadamard Matrices H(6,3) and Quaternary Hermitian Self-Dual Codes of Length 18". Thanks.

Comment: In this context, $S_{18}$ cannot be a group. If a code is equivalent to *something*, then *something* must be a code, too.